# Python Keras Recurrent Lambda Layer

Tags: python, keras, lambda, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

I'm new in keras and try to write a mixed neural network with lambda functions and dense layers. I need to write a lambda layer, with a recursive function (which needs his last output as input like the function below).

Is it possible to write a custom recurrent lambda layer in Keras such as following?

```
y(t) = y(t-1) * (x(t)-x(t-1))
```